# Span is being removed from html while saving CMS block (Magento version 2.3.0)

Tags: magento2-3

Below is my html code that I want to add in one of the CMS block.

```
<ul class="header-social">
<li><a href="{{store url=''}}"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=''}}"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=''}}"><span class="fa fa-google-plus "></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

When I saved above code in static block, it will remove span from above html content and it just display like below

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code

```
<ul class="header-social">
<li><a href="{{store url=''}}"><span class="fa fa-facebook"><em class="hidden">hidden</em></span></a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=''}}"><span class="fa fa-twitter"><em class="hidden">hidden</em></span></a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=''}}"><span class="fa fa-google-plus "><em class="hidden">hidden</em></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Add this css

```
.hidden {
    display: block!important;
    border: 0!important;
    margin: 0!important;
    padding: 0!important;
    font-size: 0!important;
    line-height: 0!important;
    width: 0!important;
    height: 0!important;
    overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by default magento's editor  will remove all empty elements, so for your case both span & anchor tags are empty, the solution is to add   if you do not want to have any text, e.g.

```
<li><a href="{{store url=''}}"><span class="fa fa-facebook">&nbsp;</span></a></li>
```

I tried and working fine for me, please upvote if problem resolved for you.